# Asymptotic distribution of ratio / multiplication of two variables

Tags: convergence-divergence, asymptotics, estimation, law-of-large-numbers

Suppose $\rightarrow_D $ denotes convergence in distribution. 
If we know

$$
f_1 \rightarrow_D W_1
$$
$$
f_2 \rightarrow_D W_2
$$
Can we say something about the convergence of 
$$
f_1 f_2 \rightarrow_D ?
$$
$$
f_1 /  f_2 \rightarrow_D ?
$$

Answer (score 0):

**Hint:** for the case where $W_{2}$ is a constant, see [Slutsky's Theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Slutsky%27s_theorem) .